# Como validar que el nombre del archivo no contenga espacios y/o caracteres especiales

Tags: javascript, html

Estoy buscando la forma de validar que los nombres de los archivos que voy a subir no contengan espacios y/o caracteres especiales, lo que tengo desarrollado hasta el momento es la carga de archivos junto con una validación en donde verifico que el nombre de ambos archivos que voy a subir contengan el mismo nombre.

```js
function ValidarArchivos(){
  
    var ValorPDF = $('#pdfToUpload').val();
    var ValorXML = $('#XmlToUpload').val();
    if(ValorPDF != "" && ValorPDF != undefined && ValorXML != "" && ValorXML != undefined ){
        var ValidarNombrePDF = document.getElementById('pdfToUpload').files[0].name;
        var ValidarNombreXML = document.getElementById('XmlToUpload').files[0].name;
        var NombrePDF= ValidarNombrePDF.substring(0, ValidarNombrePDF.length - 4);
        var NombreXML= ValidarNombreXML.substring(0, ValidarNombreXML.length - 4);
        if(NombrePDF == NombreXML){
            //alert("Los datos son correctos. ");
           
        }else{
            alert("Favor de validar que los documentos correspondan con el mismo nombre. ");
            $('#XmlToUpload').val('');
            $('#pdfToUpload').val('');
        }
    }
}
```

```html
<form action="" enctype="multipart/form-data">
          <div class="form-group row">
                        <label for="fileToUpload" class="col-sm-3 col-form-label"> Archivo XML:</label>
              <div class="col-sm-8">
                <input type="file" name="fileToUpload" id="XmlToUpload" class="btn" accept=".xml" onchange="ValidarArchivos()" required="">
              </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group row">
                         <label for="pdfToUpload" class="col-sm-3 col-form-label">Archivo PDF:</label>
              <div class="col-sm-8">
              <input type="file" name="pdfToUpload" id="pdfToUpload" class="btn" accept=".pdf" onchange="ValidarArchivos()" required="">
              </div>
                    </div>      
              </div>

          <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Cancelar</button>
            <button type="button" id="upload" class="btn btn-success" disabled="">Subir Documentos</button>
          </div>
      </form>
```

Pero aquí es necesario verificar que el nombre de ambos archivos tanto el XML como el PDF no contengan espacios y/o caracteres especiales, estaré muy agradecido si encuentro una solución para concluir esta validación.

Comment: Creo que el enfoque no es el adecuado, piensa que hay usuarios inexpertos que no sabrán como renombrar un archivo y te corresponde _"facilitarles la vida"_ remplazando (o eliminando) desde tu script esos espacios o caracteres especiales, de preferencia, en el servidor.

Comment: @Triby También lo vi desde el mismo punto, en que los usuarios no saben como renombrar pero en este caso en especifico si es necesario que lo hagan, ya que luego voy a necesitar hacer uso de dicho archivo sin espacios ni caracteres especiales, ya estudie todas las posibles pero no me queda de otra.

Comment: Mi mejor cliente siempre exige que evite complicaciones al usuario y no suponer que sabe cómo hacer las cosas. Afortunadamente, eso me ha evitado muchos problemas. Si es para facturas, desde el servidor puedes renombrar fácilmente y establecer un formato que te sea útil, por ejemplo: `idCliente-folioFactura-fecha.xml`, resultando en algo como `123-456-20210601.xml`. De esta forma, tú tienes el control y no dependes de que el usuario sepa (o quiera) hacer las cosas correctamente.

Comment: Probaste con un RegEx?

Comment: Como comenta @AugustoM, si es requerido que no se modifique el nombre por el servidor, puedes usar una expresión regular, te recomiendo echarle un vistaso a esta página https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_regexp.asp

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Quizá  puedas  utilizar la siguiente  expresión  regular:

```
   ([^-\w.]*)
```

La expresión  [^-\w.] significa:

```
 ^  : No 
 -  : el guión
 \w : los rangos a-z, A-Z, 0-9 y _
 .  : el punto
```

En otras  palabras dices captura todos  los caracteres excepto el -,letra minuscula o mayúscula, un numero o _ o un punto. Con ello podemos reemplazar  lo caracteres que  están en ese grupo:

```
  let regex = /([^-\w.]*)/gm;
 
  let NombrePDFNuevo = NombrePDF.replace(regex, ''); 

  let NombreXMLNuevo = NombreXML.replace(regex,'');

  if(NombrePDFNuevo  === NombrePDF)  {
    // el nombre es  correcto
  }
```

Agregandolo con a tu función, quedaría así:

```
function ValidarArchivos(){
  
    var ValorPDF = $('#pdfToUpload').val();
    var ValorXML = $('#XmlToUpload').val();
    if(ValorPDF != "" && ValorPDF != undefined && ValorXML != "" && ValorXML != undefined ){
        var ValidarNombrePDF = document.getElementById('pdfToUpload').files[0].name;
        var ValidarNombreXML = document.getElementById('XmlToUpload').files[0].name;

        // El nombre de archivo  solo debe contener letras, numeros, guiones y puntos


       // NOTA: Lo Agregue poe si acaso:

      // Quito el path (si  viene)
        var arcPDF = ValidarNombrePDF.replace(/^.*[\\\/]/,'');
        var arcXML = ValidarNombreXML.replace(/^.*[\\\/]/,'');

      // Valido nombres
        var regex = /([^-\w.]*)/gm; 

        var arcPDF2  = arcPDF.replace(regex, ''); 
        var  arcXML2  = arcXML.replace(regex, ''); 
        
        if( !(arcPDF==arcPDF2)  || !(arcXML==arcXML2)) {
            alert("Favor de validar que los nombres de documentos no tengan espacios ni cualquier caracter diferente a  letras, numeros, guiones y puntos");
            return;
        }
        // Verificar  que tengan el  mismo nombre  raiz
        var NombrePDF= arcPDF.substring(0, arcPDF.length - 4);
        var NombreXML= arcXML.substring(0, arcXML.length - 4);

        if(NombrePDF == NombreXML){
            //alert("Los datos son correctos. ");
        }else{
            alert("Favor de validar que los documentos correspondan con el mismo nombre. ");
            $('#XmlToUpload').val('');
            $('#pdfToUpload').val('');
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Puedes ajustar tu respuesta al código que agregue en mi pregunta inicial para darle validez a tu respuesta.

Comment: Lo mejoré. No sé si  pueda tener problemas  de sintaxis.

Comment: Respuesta clara y concisa

Answer (score 0):

Intentar probar con esta variable que borra un espacio

```
var sinEspacio = replace(/ /g, ""));

if ( sinEspacio.test(ValorPDF) ) { 
 
}
```

Comment: Gracias por tu contribución c: Vendría genial que explicaras lo que hace tu código tanto para el OP como para personas que vean tu respuesta en el futuro.

Comment: ¿\s no es espacio también?

Comment: Ok. Modifiqué el código por lo de ahora